# Rolling up records using a case statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to roll up the null in the statement so it will return just one recorde, It currently is returning 6 records, one for each year. I would like the id returned just once with results from each year.

```
DECLARE @county nvarchar(2) = '37'

SELECT 
    A.ID,

    CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2012'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2012'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2012'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club Silver'
        else ''
    END AS '2012',

    CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PCS' 
        then 'Presidents Club Silver'
        else ''
    END AS '2013',

    CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club silver'
        else ''
    END AS '2014',

    CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2015'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club'
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2015'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2015'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2015'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club Silver'
        else ''
    END AS '2015',

    CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2016'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2016'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2016'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2016'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club Silver'
        else ''
    END AS '2016',

    CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2017'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2017'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2017'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold'
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2017'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club     Silver'
        else ''
    END AS '2017'

FROM
    basic AS b
    INNER JOIN Activity AS a ON b.ID = a.ID
WHERE
    (a.UF_3  In ('N','R'))
    AND
    (a.UF_2 = 'v')
    AND
    a.ACTION_CODES ='A'
    AND
    b.CURRENT_COUNTY = @county
    AND
    PRODUCT_CODE = 'CHAPT/37'
    AND
    A.ID = '1003986'
    AND
    CATEGORY in ('PC','PCB','PCG','PCP','PCS')
GROUP BY
    a.id,
    a.SOURCE_CODE,
    a.CATEGORY
ORDER BY
    a.id,
    a.SOURCE_CODE
```

Comment: You can greatly simplify your query by converting your repetitive `CASE` into a scalar function or a single inner subquery column which is then PIVOTed into columns.

Comment: Also, why are you storing year numbers as text?

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  I don't think it does anything really useful.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of hard to tell without data, but I think you want to remove SOURCE_CODE and CATEGORY from the grouping (i.e. just group by a.id), and add MAX( ... ) around each case statement.

As an aside '' is an empty string, not a NULL.

EDIT: created some test data for a hacked down version of the query (i.e. cut out irrelevant fields and shortened to 3 years for clarity) to show what I mean:

```
create table #basic (
    ID nvarchar(7),
    CURRENT_COUNTY nvarchar(2) 
)

insert into #basic values('1003986','37')

create table #activity (
    ID nvarchar(7),
    SOURCE_CODE nvarchar(4),
    CATEGORY nvarchar(3)
);

insert into #activity (ID, SOURCE_CODE, CATEGORY) values('1003986', '2012','PC');
insert into #activity (ID, SOURCE_CODE, CATEGORY) values('1003986', '2014','PCG');

DECLARE @county nvarchar(2) = '37'

SELECT 
    A.ID,

    MAX(CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2012'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2012'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2012'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club Silver'
        else ''
    END) AS '2012',

    MAX(CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2013'and a.category='PCS' 
        then 'Presidents Club Silver'
        else ''
    END) AS '2013',

    MAX(CASE
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PC' then 'Presidents Club' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PCB' then 'Presidents Club Broze' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PCG' then 'Presidents Club Gold' 
        when a.SOURCE_CODE='2014'and a.category='PCS' then 'Presidents Club silver'
        else ''
    END) AS '2014'

FROM #basic AS b
    INNER JOIN #Activity AS a ON b.ID = a.ID
WHERE
     b.CURRENT_COUNTY = @county
    AND A.ID = '1003986'
    AND CATEGORY in ('PC','PCB','PCG','PCP','PCS')
GROUP BY  a.id
```

returns

```
ID----- 2012----------- 2013--- 2014----------------
1003986 Presidents Club         Presidents Club Gold
```

Comment: I am looking for results like this;

Comment: You want one row for one id... so just group by id. Then because you have multiple records for each id, you need to tell it how to aggregate them. If you apply MAX to each "year" column you should get what you want. If I am misunderstanding, please provide some sample data to make it easier to see what the issue is.

Comment: MAY BE I Am not asking correctly :  I would like one record for each id. with the column header being the year with the category assicated to that year.

Comment: ID 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017
1003986 Presidents Club Presidents Club Silver Presidents Club Silver Presidents Club Silver Presidents Club Silver Presidents Club Silver

Comment: 1003986 2012 PC 1
1003986 2013 PCS 1
1003986 2014 PCS 1
1003986 2015 PCS 1
1003986 2016 PCS 1
1003986 2017 PCS 1

Answer (score 0):

Start with this query that should work:

```
SELECT a.id, a.SOURCE_CODE, a.CATEGORY, COUNT(*)
FROM basic b INNER JOIN
     Activity a
     ON b.ID = a.ID
WHERE a.UF_3  In ('N', 'R') AND
      a.UF_2 = 'v' AND
      a.ACTION_CODES = 'A' AND
      b.CURRENT_COUNTY = @county AND
      PRODUCT_CODE = 'CHAPT/37'
      A.ID = '1003986'
      CATEGORY in ('PC', 'PCB', 'PCG', 'PCP', 'PCS')
GROUP BY a.id, a.SOURCE_CODE, a.CATEGORY
ORDER BY a.id, a.SOURCE_CODE;
```

This puts the categories and source codes on different rows.  That is probably sufficient for your purposes.